# How to configure WSO2 ESB SSL access with HostnameVerifier AllowAll

Tags: ssl, wso2, wso2-esb

I have been struggling with the configuration of WSO2 ESB for a few days now when trying to access an https web service. I have followed numerous pieces of advice and what I have done so far is to 
import the web service client certificate into client-truststore.jks in repostory/resources/security
added proxy access parameters to repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml (because the ESB is behind corporate firewall)
added AllowAll parameter to transportSender https in axis2.xml
restarted esb and still get the exception

```
http-nio-9443-exec-50, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
http-nio-9443-exec-50, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
http-nio-9443-exec-50, called closeSocket()
http-nio-9443-exec-50, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching my.domain.com found
http-nio-9443-exec-50, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 1
http-nio-9443-exec-50, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 154
```

I am using jdk1.6_34 and tried with WSO2 ESB 4.5.1 and 4.6 with the same results.
The logging is showing the ssl handshake being started but then ends with the error above. All the googling suggests that the hostnameverifier parameter should do the trick but clearly doesn't. Is there somewhere else I should be configuring this or if this parameter is being overridden somewhere else? I have run out of options and places to look with this.

Edit:
I have had another attempt at this and by setting the host name in my hosts file to the CN specified in the client certificate I can now get a bit further but I am now getting another error which I can't seem to fathom out.
The specific error is "... no IV used for this cipher", but with the debug trace being

```
Found trusted certificate:
[
[
Version: V1
Subject: CN=mydomain.com, O=my o, ST=INTERFACES, C=GB
Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
   modulus:#### loads of numbers here ####
public exponent: 65537
Validity: [From: Mon Apr 22 14:26:25 BST 2013,
           To: Tue Apr 22 14:26:25 BST 2014]
Issuer: CN=ath-st2-API-a, O=Northgate IS, ST=INTERFACES, C=GB
SerialNumber: [    a4cf31a6 9c0d920d]

]
Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
Signature:
### signature here ###
]
http-nio-9443-exec-13, READ: SSLv3 Handshake, length = 98
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS
Cert Authorities:
<CN=mydomain.com, O=my o, ST=INTERFACES, C=GB>
*** ServerHelloDone
http-nio-9443-exec-13, SEND SSLv3 ALERT:  warning, description = no_certificate
http-nio-9443-exec-13, WRITE: SSLv3 Alert, length = 2
*** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, SSLv3
http-nio-9443-exec-13, WRITE: SSLv3 Handshake, length = 132
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
###master secret here ####
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 52 45 86 22 10 B0 E2 EF   19 10 B1 04 ED C9 6F B0  RE."..........o.
0010: C3 8E BC D6 2C C9 5E D0   CA 8E 88 6B 22 53 1D B0  ....,.^....k"S..
Server Nonce:
0000: 52 45 86 23 B0 56 30 EC   84 F0 48 C1 F7 31 0C 5C  RE.#.V0...H..1.\
0010: 43 B3 CB 25 DA 19 4C 0E   B1 71 CB 17 8E 0C 62 04  C..%..L..q....b.
Master Secret:
0000: C3 F4 6B 9B EB 50 67 BD   6C A8 F0 63 88 A1 5A C7  ..k..Pg.l..c..Z.
0010: E5 CD A4 9A 46 95 3F B3   13 2D 4E BF 77 2C 64 86  ....F.?..-N.w,d.
0020: 44 D2 89 B5 09 EE 96 E5   8B 8D E2 30 04 09 F2 D3  D..........0....
Client MAC write Secret:
0000: F7 76 83 C9 16 F5 CB 33   E3 43 3F 7B 68 2E 8A 6F  .v.....3.C?.h..o
Server MAC write Secret:
0000: CC FB 14 CE 21 AD C8 BC   20 C1 A5 2B 0B 2B 83 35  ....!... ..+.+.5
Client write key:
0000: 9C 9E FA A5 68 6E 27 2C   E0 6E 80 9D ED C9 1C 01  ....hn',.n......
Server write key:
0000: B7 5A 24 DD 6F 65 5A 7E   C8 AD 4A 29 E4 09 08 6D  .Z$.oeZ...J)...m
... no IV used for this cipher
http-nio-9443-exec-13, WRITE: SSLv3 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 174, 247, 182, 190, 5, 104, 242, 127, 216, 79, 94, 15, 215, 236, 236,   211, 30, 51, 116, 56, 138, 144, 19, 125, 0, 54, 52, 114, 173, 138, 170, 166, 24, 67, 108, 102 }
***
http-nio-9443-exec-13, WRITE: SSLv3 Handshake, length = 56
http-nio-9443-exec-13, READ: SSLv3 Alert, length = 2
http-nio-9443-exec-13, RECV SSLv3 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
http-nio-9443-exec-13, called closeSocket()
http-nio-9443-exec-13, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:     Received fatal alert
: handshake_failure
http-nio-9443-exec-13, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 1
http-nio-9443-exec-13, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 154
http-nio-9443-ClientPoller-0, called closeOutbound()
http-nio-9443-ClientPoller-0, closeOutboundInternal()
http-nio-9443-ClientPoller-0, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
http-nio-9443-ClientPoller-0, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 32
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
```

I have tried passing https.protocols=SSLv3,SSLv2Hello or https.protocols=SSLv3 in the axis2 config file as a  to the https sender transport but this doesn't help either.

Suggestions welcome.
thanks
Conrad

Comment: Check the certificate is issued for same domain or not?

Comment: The CN entry for the certificate isn't the same so I accept that this is why I am getting the error. I have no control over the certificate and this is why I am trying to the get the apparent documented solution of using the HostnameVerifier to work.